# F# Recursion termination

Tags: f#, recursion

I have been reading alot about functional programming and f#. I have a snippet of code that I cannot understand. I am familiar with recursive programs but this particular code is bugging me

```
open System

let rec fact x =
    if x < 1 then 1
    else x * fact (x - 1)

fact 6
```

In this snippet of code there is no where in the code that terminates the recusion. How does this program know when to stop. If I programmed this in c# I would tell the program to stop recursing when the index or iterator is higher then 6.

Comment: The index in this case is x and since it's counting down from 6, checking whehter it's higher than 6, would be what leads to an infinite loop. Checking whether it's less than 1, which this code does, is exactly right. Also note that this corresponds quite closely to the mathematical definition of factorial.

Comment: Worth noting that this has nothing to do with functional programming.

Comment: there is code that terminates the recursion, it just doesn't look like the C# counterpart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recursion stops when it `x` is less than `1` because the result of the expression is then `1`

```
if x < 1 then 1
```

In C# the function would look as follows:

```
public int fact(int x)
{
   if (x < 1)
      return 1;
   else
      return x * fact(x - 1);
}
```

Pure functional programming is interesting because there is never a return, all the program does is evaluate.  You need to ask yourself 'What does this expression evaluate to?'

Comment: The closest equivalent to F#'s if..else would be C#'s ternary conditional operator, which doesn't execute statements, but evaluates to a single value. For example: `int fact(int n) { return n < 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1); }`

Comment: Thank you ..this really helped. This functional stuff is interesting and strange